# Is there an equivalent of ComboBoxRenderer for NumericUpDown?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to draw spinner controls, such as those found on a NumericUpDown, on a custom component.  If I want to draw a drop-down button, I can use ComboBoxRenderer.  Is there an equivalent of ComboBoxRenderer for NumericUpDown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there is.  See the [VisualStyleElement.Spin class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.spin.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think a ComboBoxRenderer exists in the Windows Forms namespace. You need to directly draw the UpDown control arrows (spin buttons) using interop and the Theme API. I don't have a complete sample for you, but you'll need

```
[DllImport("uxtheme.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr OpenThemeData(IntPtr hWnd, String classList);

[DllImport("uxtheme", ExactSpelling = true)]
public extern static Int32 DrawThemeBackground(IntPtr hTheme, IntPtr hdc, int iPartId, int iStateId, ref RECT pRect, IntPtr pClipRect);

[DllImport("uxtheme.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
public extern static Int32 CloseThemeData(IntPtr hTheme);
```

and you can find the required parts and states in [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773210(VS.85).aspx) (look for the SPIN style class and its associated parts and states).